# I'm getting a "Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView"

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

I have looked at other posts to this problem and I can't seem to solve it, so I'm hoping that its just a case that I am missing something obvious.

Here is my code: 
**MainActivity.XML**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/translation_panel_blue_open_mea"
                    android:minHeight="57dp"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:subtitleTextColor="@color/header_grey_mea"
                    app:titleTextColor="@color/header_grey_mea"
                     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        app:menu="@menu/burger_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**burger_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menuLogout"
            android:onClick="initUserLogout"
            android:title="@string/log_out">

        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menuItemTutorial"
            android:onClick="launchTutorialView"
            android:title="@string/tutorial">

        </item>

    </group>
</menu>
```

**`AppTheme`**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

and my `initBurgerMenu`function that runs in `MainActivity`:

```
private fun initBurgerMenu(){
        mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navigationView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
            // set item as selected to persist highlight
            menuItem.isChecked = true
            // close drawer when item is tapped
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers()
            when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.menuLogout -> {
                   initUserLogout()
                }
                R.id.menuItemTutorial -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "tutorial", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
            true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the entire stack trace, not just the error message.

Comment: also, post your build.gradle file.

Comment: I think you meant to use (in your XML) [this NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView) as opposed to [this other](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/navigation/NavigationView). Hard to say without seeing your Gradle and imports. Seems like you're missing an AppBarLayout closing tag there? (below the Toolbar).

Comment: You **can't use** Theme.AppCompat with the material components library

Answer (score 1):

Close your AppBarLayout tag, like this

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="57dp"
            android:padding="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation view in the xml is from `com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView` and you're probably trying to inflate `NavigationView` from `android.support.design.widget`, if this is the problem just delete the import and reimport the correct package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:
This happened after updating various dependencies to latest.
I updated the `com.google.android.material:material` from `1.4.0-beta01` to `1.7.0-alpha01`.
After reverting the version to `1.4.0-beta01` the problem resolved.